# Is it possible to change a ble device's raw(advertising) data on Android

Tags: android, ibeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop an android application that scan ble(ibeacon) devices and get them advertising data(I am parsing it and get some values like temperature value or beacon name.). But now I need to manipulate this data from android device. Is it possible to manipulate this data from android app? If it is then how? Can anybody help ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the manipulated data?  Just use it within the application or re-transmit it as a beacon?  Also note that the beacon name is typically not part of a beacon transmission, it is usually part of a bluetooth device's "scan response" which provides the name of the bluetooth device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want manipulate this data because I want to assing for example department names into this data(Because of app get the beacon it will say yes you are in blabla department ). So after future usages I want to change this department name from android app if it is possible.

Comment: I see, so you want to *reconfigure* the beacon?  What make and model of beacons are you using?  The answer is different for each.

Comment: MiniBeacons I guess. They are same as in this pic. http://g01.s.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1lMmfHXXXXXXaapXXq6xXFXXXA/201245151/HTB1lMmfHXXXXXXaapXXq6xXFXXXA.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately there is no standard API to configure beacons** (change the values of the fields they advertise).  Some manufacturers provide an API to do this over Bluetooth LE, some to not.  You must check with the manufacturer of your beacon to see if they provide a public API to change the beacon configuration, and then you may be able to code an Android app to do this.   Whether you can do so and how you do so will be different for each beacon make and model.

For the case of the beacons used in the question above, it appears there is no API available to do this.  The sales page below shows that their is an iOS app to configure the beacons, but it does not mention anything about an API that will let you do the same.

http://minew.en.alibaba.com/product/60193606262-220649015/CE_FCC_certified_indoor_location_advertisements_nRF51822_chipset_bluetooth_beacon_ble_ibeacon.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand there is no way to configure this devices over BLE than may I ask which brand or model will allow this operation?